# How to get the private key from seed phrase and account number generated by Coinbase Commerce?

Tags: wallets, ethers.js, polygon

I have:

- my 12-word seed phrase
- an account address (0x..) associated with this seed phrase

I don't, however, have the private key to that specific account. Is there any way to retrieve the private key of that specific account from the seed phrase?

For context, this is a wallet that was generated by Coinbase Commerce. I'm trying to retrieve funds that were sent to the Coinbase Commerce deposit wallet, but on a wrong network.

Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I have tried a brute force approach by generating ~1million wallet addresses from the mnemonic without any luck.

Comment: Have you tried loading it into metamask and revealing the private phrase from there?

Comment: Yes, I have. But I couldn't get the exact account (0x..) I need.

Answer (score 1):

NEVER COPY YOUR PRIVATE KEY ON A WEBSITE, but

There is a website which provides you the public addresses and private keys that mnemonic will generate. Try that. Maybe you can find that address and its respective private key.

```
https://iancoleman.io/bip39/
```

Comment: NEVER EVER input a seed phrase on a website, even if it seems legit. I'm not saying this one is legit or it's not legit. Uour seed phrase is private information, sharing it can (will) lead to loss of fund/tokens.